# How to get a status of a running query in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have a select query running very long. How will I get a status of that query, like how long will it be running? Whether it is accessing a data from the tables or not.

Note : As per `pg_stat_activity` the query state is shown as active and not in a waiting state.
Like in Oracle, we can see the source/target and processing status of a query - is there something like this in postgresql?

Comment: I need a completion time of a query in the above question. pg_stat_activity view gives only the active queries, database, user detail. pg_stat_activity do not contains the completion time of a running query.

Answer (score 73):

Based on @Anshu answer I am using:

```
SELECT datname, pid, state, query, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) AS age 
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state <> 'idle' 
    AND query NOT LIKE '% FROM pg_stat_activity %' 
ORDER BY age;
```

Comment: `AND <> 'idle in transaction'` may also be of interest

Answer (score 10):

we can find the query log with respect to the database in postgres .

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'yourdatabasename'
```

This will give active query log of database .

Answer (score 9):

This can't be done yet, but is on [the TODO](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Query_progress_indication).